# Bottom Sheet content is showing for a second before activity content in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

I have implemented bottom sheet in jetpack compose with `BottomSheetScaffold` in a screen and default state is `initialValue = BottomSheetValue.Collapsed`.
When screen appears on device then Bottom sheet content is displayed for a second and then activity scope layout are presented and then bottom sheet behaves like it should. I am trying to remove this glitch from bottom sheet. Please let me know the suggestions which I can implement to remove this glitch.

Bottom sheet is working fine but it appears for a second before screen content and then disappears. This glitch needs to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a **state** for initial value storage, try

```
rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
    )
```

I use this way to show the bottom sheets

```
val bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
)
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetState = bottomSheetState,
    sheetContent = {
        //Sheet content
    },
    scrimColor = <SCREEN OVERLAY COLOR>,
    sheetBackgroundColor = <BACKGROUND COLOR>
) {//Your Screen Code}
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: I used ModalBottomSheetLayout instead of BottomSheetScaffold and it worked.